# How do I set values nested within multiple Options if they are not already set?

Tags: rust, config, mutability

I have a configuration setup such as this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Config {
    defaults: Option<Default>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Default {
    duration: Option<Millis>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Millis(u64);
```

Having a value of `let cfg: &mut Config`, how could I easily set the duration of this value?

I tried this, which panics if the value is not there to begin with:

```
*cfg.default.as_mut().unwrap().duration.as_mut().unwrap() = Millis(1234)
```

I  have not found a way around those `unwrap`s to create the values on demand other than this, which is even more verbose...

```
if cfg.defaults.is_none() {
    cfg.defaults = Some(Default { duration: None });
}

if cfg.defaults.as_mut().unwrap().duration.is_none() {
    cfg.defaults.as_mut().unwrap().duration = Some(Millis(1234));
}
```

What's "The Way" to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the [`get_or_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert) method is for:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Config {
    defaults: Option<Default>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Default {
    duration: Option<Millis>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Millis(u64);

fn main() {
    let mut config = Config { defaults: None };

    config
        .defaults
        .get_or_insert(Default { duration: None })
        .duration
        .get_or_insert(Millis(0))
        .0 = 42;

    // Config { defaults: Some(Default { duration: Some(Millis(42)) }) }
    println!("{:?}", config);
}
```

[(link to playground)](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=0b59ae42db6a5011da196718598e4c8c&version=stable)

Comment: Nice! And there's also a `get_or_insert_with` if the computation to obtain the default is expensive.

Comment: Noice. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Although the last get_or_insert can insert the actual data, but I suspect it was written like that for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use pattern matching:

```
if let Some(Config { defaults: Some(Default { duration: Some(ref mut millis) }) }) = cfg {
    *millis = 1234;
}
```

Or, alternatively, with nested `if let`s:

```
if let Some(Config { ref mut defaults }) = cfg {
    if let Some(Default { ref mut duration }) = *defaults {
        *duration = Some(Millis(1234))
    }
}
```

This won't create values on demand, however. There is no simple boilerplate-less way to do it, as far as I'm aware. One of the approaches would be defining your own accessor methods which would handle defaults instantiation upon access:

```
impl Config {
    fn defaults(&mut self) -> &mut Default {
        if let Some(ref mut defaults) = *self.defaults {
            defaults
        } else {
            self.defaults = Some(Defaults::new());  // assuming that Defaults::new() exists
            self.defaults.as_mut().unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

If you have such a method for every field of every structure, you will be able to do this:

```
*cfg.defaults().duration() = 1234;
```